# ¿Quisiera migrar archivos de Azure a otro Azure?

Tags: azure, servicio, migration, migracion

Solicito información sobre estos servicios que encontré sobre migración:

**Migrar(Carpetas, Archivos e imagenes) con almacenamiento de TB.**

**Servicios:**

- Azure File Sync (gratis).
- Datadobi Servicio de Migración Datadobi-SEL Datadobi ($1,098.00).
- Komprise. ($15,000.00 por año).
- Data Dynamics.  Patrocinado por Azure (StorageX para migraciones a Azure).
- Atempo   (Programa Azure).

¿Podrías darme los precios promedio o si el servicio Azure File Sync es gratuito o hasta que cierto punto?

Gracias por la información.

Dame información por favor.

Comment: Faltan datos aquí. ¿Qué clase de migración se quiere hacer? Me refiero, entre cuentas de Storage, a una suscripción distinta, otro inquilino... ¿Y cuántos GB o TB de datos se desean mover?

Comment: Respondiendo al título: no, no sé si quieres migrar archivos. Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: migrar archivos es super simple y debiese ser tan facil como usar  `sync` sobre `ssh y listo.

Comment: quisiera migrar archivos, como carpetas e imágenes de TB de almacenamiento,